# Utilizando a instrução case SQL Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte sql no firebird.

```
select distinct tb_proostarefas.*,
(case
    WHEN (tb_proostarefas.dt_prev is null and tb_proostarefas.dt_vencimento < date) then 1
    When (tb_proostarefas.dt_prev is not null and tb_proostarefas.dt_prev < date) then 2
    When (tb_proostarefas.dt_prev is not null and tb_proostarefas.dt_prev >= date) then 3
  else 3 end) AS 'STATUS'
from tb_proostarefas
order by tb_proostarefas.gut desc, tb_proostarefas.dt_vencimento
```

estou com o seguinte erro:

```
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 3, column 83.
).
```

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Ele não está reconhecendo esse "date". O que você quer usar aí? Seria a data atual?
"Token unknown - line 3, column 83."

Comment: Completando o que o amigo acima disse, se voce quer que ele retorne a data atual coloque o comando current_date

Answer (score 2):

A sintaxe da construção `CASE` não está de acordo com a documentação do firebird, pelo menos não com [esse link.](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-case.html)

Para exemplificar, vamos supor que temos o um banco com uma tabela chamada `Products`, com os seguintes campos:

```
ProductID   ProductName      SupplierID   CategoryID    Unit                  Price
1           Chais            1            1             10 boxes x 20 bags    18
2           Chang            1            1             24 - 12 oz bottles    19
3           Aniseed Syrup    1            2             12 - 550 ml bottles   10

....
```

Agora vamos construir uma expressão `CASE` para extrair `ProductName`, `Preço` e as categorias, mas estas nomeadas de acordo com o ID, da seguinte maneira:

```
Caso id=1, 'Categoria 1'
Caso id=2, 'Cateogira 2'
Caso id=7, 'Categproa 7'
Se nenhuma das anteriores, 'Outras'
```

Construiremos a expressao de acordo com essa sintaxe ([Simple CASE](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-case.html#langrefupd15-case-simple)):

```
CASE <expression>
   WHEN <exp1> THEN result1
   WHEN <exp2> THEN result2
   ...
   [ELSE defaultresult]
END
```

Então nossa expressão seria:

```
SELECT 
  ProductName, Price,
  case Categoryid
    when 1 then 'Categoria 1'
    when 2 then 'Categoria 2'
    when 7 then 'Cateroria 7'
    else 'Outras'
  end as category
from Products
```

Para ver o resultado copie a expressão acima e cole no espaço para declaração da expressão [SQL desse link.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in)